# Passing string result to query then export as csv

Tags: string, vba, ms-access, export, criteria

Good Afternoon,
I have an access query that contains a list of all my customers lets call that CUS
I have another query that has a list of ORDERS

I would like to write some VBS that cycles through the customer list and exports a csv file containing all orders that belong to that customer.

The vba would then move on to the next customer on the list and perform the same action.

Any help would be great.

Snippet of code below

almost there cant get the WHERE condition working it keeps displaying a popup for me to populate however the same string is feeding the msgbox fine here is a snippet below tht is within the loop

```
strcustcode = rs!OCUSTCODE 
ordercount = rs!orders 
TIMEFILE = Format$(Time, "HHMM") 
MsgBox ([strcustcode] & " has " & [ordercount] & " orders") 
StrSQL = "Select * From [24-ND_Cus] where [24-ND_Cus].[OCUSTCODE] = strcustcode " 
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("tmpExport", StrSQL) 
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport", "c:file.csv" db.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpExport" –
```

Comment: Hi Leon welcome to Stack...

Comment: Could you add what you tried .. it would be great.

Comment: almost there cant get the WHERE condition working it keeps displaying a popup for me to populate however the same string is feeding the msgbox fine
here is a snippet below tht is within the loop

strcustcode = rs!OCUSTCODE
ordercount = rs!orders
TIMEFILE = Format$(Time, "HHMM")

   MsgBox ([strcustcode] & " has " & [ordercount] & " orders")
   StrSQL = "Select * From [24-ND_Cus] where [24-ND_Cus].[OCUSTCODE] = strcustcode "
   Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("tmpExport", StrSQL)
   DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport", "c:file.csv"
   db.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpExport"

Comment: Please "edit" the question (the link is just below the tags below the question) and insert your code into the question itself - it is nearly impossible to read code in comments, and the question needs to be "self-contained".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use [ ] around VBA variables. Don't use parens for the MsgBox when you just want to give user a message. The parens make it a function that requires a response by user to set a variable.

`MsgBox strcustcode & " has " & ordercount & " orders"`

Concatenate the variable into the SQL statement. If OCUSTCODE is a text type field, use apostrophe delimiters for the parameter.

`StrSQL = "Select * From [24-ND_Cus] Where [OCUSTCODE] = '" & strcustcode & "'"`

I don't advise code that routinely modifies design and changing a query SQL statement is changing design. If the only change is filter criteria and a dynamic parameterized query won't work, I suggest a 'temp' table - table is permanent, data is temporary. Delete and write records to the table and export the table.